# Is there any difference between just returning a value and by using Future.value(); in Dart?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, future

For example, is there any difference between those two code snippets? In dartpad, they return the same thing at the same time.

Does the function itself infer the returning value as `bool` from the function declaration (`Future<bool>`) so that using just '`return`' is okay or is there any specific situation that make difference?

A:

```
Future<bool> anyFunction() async {
 print('start');
 var temp = Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
 bool result = await getSomeResult();
 print('end');

 return result;
}
```

B:

```
Future<bool> anyFunction() async {
 print('start');
 var temp = Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
 bool result = await getSomeResult();
 print('end');

 return Future<bool>.value(result);
}
```

Comment: they are the same, however `A` is more "natural"

Comment: Yup both are same but in first case compiler will be more aware of what you are trying to return so will help you in compile time function access and all other stuff.

Comment: @UTKARSHSharma and in second case compiler does not do that?

Comment: Oops sry i didn't see that , so there are no change at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's been years since no answer but only comments, I'll post what I've found here.

(Thanks to both @pskink and @UTKARSH-Sharma)

1. They will give the exact same `value`. You can choose either of them freely.
2. For The first `return result`, Dart will infer the type and wrap it in a `Future<bool>`.
3. The second `Future<bool>.value(result)` is just a more explicit expression.

In conclusion, they **both are valid**, choose what you simply prefer.